# Writing a regex command to split an array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regex is one of those things I've wanted to be able to write myself and although I have a basic understand of how it works I've never found myself in the situation where I needed to use it where it doesn't exist already widely on the web (such as for validating email addresses).

A problem that I have is that I am receiving a string which is comma separated, however some of the string values contain commas also. For example I might receive:

> $COMMAND=1,2,3,"string","another,string",4,5,6

Generally I will never receive anything like this, however the device sending me this string array allows for it to happen so I would like to be able to split the array accordingly if it ever were to occur.

So obviously just splitting it like so (where `rawResponse` has the `$COMMAND=` part removed:

```
string[] response = rawResponse.Split(',');
```

Is not good enough! I think regex is the correct tool for the job, could anyone help me write it?

Comment: so, "another,string" = one unit?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's not the intended use of the unit as I said, but it is allowed for some reason!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string rawResponse = @"1,2,3,""string"",""another,string"",4,5";
string pattern = @"[^,""]+|""([^""]*)""";
foreach(Match match in  Regex.Matches(rawResponse, pattern))
       // use match.Value
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
"string"
"another,string"
4
5
```

If you need response as array of strings you can use Linq:

```
var response = Regex.Matches(rawResponse, pattern).Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Now I've integrated it, I will do my best to understand it! :D

Comment: Thanks for the ToArray example btw! +1 Is the `m => m.Value` known as a lambda expression or have I mis-remembered something else?

Comment: @ing0 it matches either one or more characters which is not comma or quotes, or it matches anything between quoutes (which is not quotes)

Comment: I understand that some people dislike regex but SO is not necessarily for opinions! I asked a question asking specifically for regex and with two or three lines of code in a answer I had the problem fixed within 5 minutes! Thanks again!

Comment: -1 I down voted because using a regular expression is not a good way to handle this. Sure it works - but the person who asked the question *doesn't even understand it* which means that maintainability is 0%. The question was essentially about parsing CSV - and this *is* a poor way to approach that...shoot me down if you like but that is how I see it.

Comment: @Fraser actually I upvoted your answer, in spite of it was not about Regex, which was asked for. I will not remove my upvote, so you can leave your downvote. Its up to you. And I am completely sure that `TextFieldParser` will work slower than simple regular expression (internally it also uses regular expressions). Also it requires stream instead of string - that's not convenient at all.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - you know what, I had my coffee and thought better of it. I will remove the down vote asap :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalString = @"1,2,3,""string"",""another,string"",4,5,6";
string regexPattern = @"(("".*?"")|(.*?))(,|$)";
foreach(Match match in  Regex.Matches(originalString, regexPattern))
{

}
```